# Text fields in master–detail view show ( "<null>" ... instead of correct value

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, cocoa-bindings

I'm following Aaron Hillegrass's book (trying), and am at the point trying to bind some view cells. I am getting the results in the screen shot below.

The cells on the right side are at least editable. The title cell is not.

I'd appreciate any advice on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You need to show us some code as well.

Comment: The whole point of this exercise - is that there isn't any code - everything is done in interface builder.. It's great but a little hard to get a handle on - or to debug..

Comment: Screenshots of the binding statements then?

Comment: I got it... I had to bind the table (a single column) to the entity/arrangedObject, then bind the table view cell to objectValue.name.. phew..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my last comment. I had to bind the table to entity > arrangedObject, then bind the tableView cells to objectValue.name.